# How to retrieve value from span in class

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to click on hospital panel. The  contains a class attribute and inner text and i need to click on "后三".
I get an error saying "unable to locate element". What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<span class="tab-back" value="2" tag="0" default="0"><span class="tabbar-left"></span><span class="content">后三</span><span class="tabbar-right"></span></span>
```

CODE :

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='content']/text()[last()]"));
```

it's seems not getting the value of 后三. Kindly advise

Comment: Can you show the line of code with the Java Selenium call. For example, `driver.getElement(...);`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I repost the java selenium call , kindly advise

Comment: Can you just use: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='content']"));`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis i can't use this method as there is alot class called content

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis i encounter an error of Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='content']"}

Comment: Try this :- 

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
  element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='content']")));
String value = element.getText();

Comment: @pArAs i get the weird value from the element.getText. Although i change the to UTF-8 but still the same of the encoding error

Comment: see once you get the string in `java` you can't change it to any other encoding. internally a `java` string is always encoded in UTF-16. If you want the exact value you have to convert the same before getting the string from `element.getText()` method.

Comment: @pArAs hi paras , do you mind to show me how to convert the UT6-16 to UTF-8?

Comment: @JaydenNg, what you need to do is, first based upon your locale try to find out what is `Accept-Charset` header for your browser. e.g. for my locale the browser supports `ISO-8859-1` so I would use something like:-

`byte ptext[] = element.getText().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath below:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='content' and contains(text(),'后三')]"));
```

And if multiple elements there, you can use:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='content' and contains(text(),'后三')]"));
```

The desired item you can access by for example:

```
elements.get(index)
```

Where index is your desired index like 0,1 etc.